# discord.js v13 TypeError: Cannot read property 'createMessageCollector' of undefined

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I keep getting an error ever since I updated to discord.js v13. Can anyone help me out?

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'createMessageCollector' of undefined
```

Code:

```
        var TitleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor(Color.general)
            .setTitle(`${Mode} Post Title`)
            .setDescription(`Please enter a title for your post, it should summarise your description in a few words. If selling, you should also include whether you're for hire, or selling assets.`);
        const TitleEmbedSent = await Message.author.send({ embeds: [TitleEmbed] }).then(msg => msg.channel).catch(() => {
            return Message.channel.send(`Sorry ${Message.author}, but I couldn't direct Message you!`)
        });
        const Collector = TitleEmbedSent.channel.createMessageCollector({ MessageFilter, max: 1, time: 300000 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go forward by this

```js
var TitleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor(Color.general)
            .setTitle(`${Mode} Post Title`)
            .setDescription(`Please enter a title for your post, it should summarise your description in a few words. If selling, you should also include whether you're for hire, or selling assets.`);
        try {
            Message.author.send({ embeds: [TitleEmbed] }).then(msg => {
                 const collector = msg.channel.createMessageCollector({ MessageFilter, max: 1, time: 300000 }));
            });
        } catch (err) {
            return Message.channel.send(`Sorry ${Message.author}, but I couldn't direct Message you!`);
        }
```

The issues with your code is that you declared variable `TitleEmbedSent` with `message.channel` which clearly in this code means DMChannel, that is good but when you go create your `MessageCollector` you try to find `.channel` again by doing

```js
const Collector = TitleEmbedSent.channel.createMessageCollector({ MessageFilter, max: 1, time: 300000 });
```

`TitleEmbed` is already a channel, you can't get `channel` out of `channel`.